# unable to move VSTEST coded ui tests to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, vstest

I have a suite of working Coded UI tests, written in C#, all marked as [TestMethod], written in VS 2013 and running on a set of VMWare machines, using the MS Test Agent (version 12.0).
I am building a release pipeline in Azure DevOps and use the following tasks:
Visual Studio Test Platform Installer (selected version 15.9.2)
VsTest - Test Assemblies (selected Visual Studio 2015 as this is the lowest version)

All of the test DLLs are at a specific folder on the VM I'm running and they are all copied from the deployment folder of an actual working VMWare machine. The test directories of the tasks are pointing to that folder.
I tried running .orderedtests file in the test assemblies section of the VsTest, but got an error that no tests were found.
I then switched to a *.dll so I can just see some tests recognized and running.
At this point I just want to see tests running. I don't care for the results.
In this scenario - letting the VsTest task discover the available tests, I get the following error:

> ##[error]The slice of type 'Discovery' is 'Aborted' because of the error : System.Exception: No test is available in [some
> folder]\Some-File.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are
> registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate
> and try again.

What am I missing and what is needed to be able to run those 2013 (12.0) tests, which are working perfectly on local VMs, on the Azure DevOps pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The slice of type 'Discovery' is 'Aborted' because of the error : System.Exception: No test is available in [some folder]\Some-File.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Based on the error message, you can try to can specify the appropriate framework and platform in the vstest task.

For example:

```
/Platform: x64 /Framework: framework40
```

[image]

For more info, you could refer to this doc: [VSTest.Console.exe command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019)

On the other hand, since you can run the test on your local machine successfully, you can also try to use the self-hosted agent.

Comment: yep. i did just that. doesn't help one bit.
i am currently trying to run the test as AZURE cmd task and run a VSTEST command line with arguments
i will have to return to it. thanks for the tip.

Comment: If all methods doesn't work, I suggest that you can use the self-hosted agent